# In Annihilation, why is it important to keep Lena's husband's past a secret?

Tags: annihilation

In Annihilation (the movie) 5 women go on a dangerous expedition. Lena's husband went on a similar previous expedition. We are told 3 of the women don't know that Lena's husband went on a previous similar expedition and we are told they might not react well to that news.

Why does it matter? What possible reason would knowing that Lena's husband went on a previous expedition matter one bit to anyone?

As mentioned from the script

> DR VENTRESS: Given the track record, it hasn’t been easy to find volunteers...
>
> LENA waits, letting the doctor talk herself round.
>
> DR VENTRESS (CONT’D): If you were to join us, I don’t think it would be wise to explain your connection to the previous mission. It might not be... helpful. To the group dynamic.

Why? Imagine the other 3 women did know that Lena's husband had been on a previous mission. How would that have effectived the group dynamic?

It's not like Lena was there to rescue her husband and might therefore choose to sacrifice the team or anything of that nature. Lena is not her husband so no one would think "Your husband did something crazy so you're also going to do something crazy". We don't make that assumption in the real world so that's not a motivation to suggest that there is any reason not to tell the other 3 women about Lena's past.

Is there some other reason I missed?

Answer (score 3):

The secretive woman in charge of the covert Southern Reach, Dr. Ventress, doesn't want the other women to know about Lena's relation to Kane because they are already suspicious about the circumstances of his survival and she doesn't want that to affect the team she's carefully arranged. She also wants another team member who's beholden to her and her driving goal of reaching the source of the Shimmer.

The other women going on the mission know the previous all-male missions have been unsuccessful and the assumption is that the men killed each other. At least one of the other women is certain that the only man who's returned -- Kane -- killed another member of his team who was also going to successfully leave the Area X.

This is from a version of the script at https://scriptslug.com/scripts/annihilation-2018:

> DR VENTRESS: Given the track record, it hasn’t been easy to find volunteers...
>
> LENA waits, letting the doctor talk herself round.
>
> DR VENTRESS (CONT’D): If you were to join us, I don’t think it would be wise to explain your connection to the previous mission. It might not be... helpful. To the group dynamic.

Later in the movie, after the women see a video recording of Kane appearing to mutilate a fellow member of his team, Ventress comments to Lena:

> DR VENTRESS: Incidentally, Lena, I just wanted to say: on top of whatever else isgoing here, you shouldn’t worry.
> LENA: '.. Worry about what?
> DR VENTRESS: Your secret. It’s safe with me.
>
> LENA pauses.
>
> LENA: ‘My secret’. You’re talking about my husband?
>
> LENA lowers her voice.
>
> LENA (CONT’D): Is that not our secret? In that you were the one who instructed me to keep it.
>
> DR VENTRESS shrugs.

So Ventress has set the hook.

Later, team member Sheppard goes missing, and it's Lena who volunteers to go and look for her, later returning to confirm that Sheppard is dead, making her  -- like her husband -- the only member of a team connected to the death of another team member.

This is a point that Thorensen makes when she snaps in the villa after finding Kane's photo in Lena's locket and she ties up Lena and Ventress:

> THORENSEN: You think I don’t know this whole thing’s a set-up? You two - you’ve been working together. You tricked us. You lied to us. You led us here.

Then the bear-thing breaks into the villa, interrupting Thorensen's rant, eventually killing her and critically injuring Radek.

Comment: It's still not at all clear to me why it was important to keep that a secret. They all knew everyone who's entered has not returned. In the real world no one blames a partner for whatever there SO did. It's like "Oh your husband killed someone on a mission therefore I believe you're untrustworthy and I believe you'll also kill someone". No one does that in the real world so I still don't see what in the story would make telling the other 3 women about Lena's husband would have on them.

Comment: I probably need to restructure the answer a little bit. It's mostly a set-up by Ventress -- she talks Lena into concealing the information from the rest of the team, and the longer Lena withholds the information the more damning for her it will be if they find out. (The Southern Reach itself is also very compartmentalized and covert, as described in the novels.) Ventress's scheme also parallels the government's paranoia about Area X; they've been determined from the start to keep the Shimmer's existence hidden from the general public. The longer they wait, the more damning it seems.

Comment: Why will it be damning? Seems to me it's just one of those "why didn't you tell us?" "Because it didn't come up".  "Why didn't you tell us you took ballet in high school?", "Because it didn't come up". It's irrelevant to any kind of suspicion. Imagine a team of soldiers go into enemy territory. "Why didn't you tell us your wife was killed in this town?" "Because ... I don't like to think about it", "Because it's none of your business". "Because it's irrelevant, we're here on the mission"... etc. Unless there is something more I missed, nothing was mentioned in the movie to make it suspicious.